# What is the difference between single or double quotes in a formula?

Tags: formula, process-builder

For example is there any difference in:

```
CONTAINS(User.Id, " 123456789 " )
```

or

```
CONTAINS(User.Id, ' 123456789 ' )
```

I am using this in the process builder and have been passed a formula written by someone else. I want to know for future reference what the correct one is (I can see on the [Salesforce formula page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0) that it uses " ") and why.

Comment: It doesn't matters IMO, both works well.

Comment: Okay great - if there is no difference between them when it comes to the function of them in formulas then I will simply continue to use consistently across my formulas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**They exhibit the same behavior.** One thing I do in Visualforce formulas and carry over into formulas elsewhere is that I use double quotes to emphasize the difference between Apex and what I am working on. But the two different types of quotation marks are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know,

we use,

**Double quote** to Represent string **"String"**
**Single Quote** represent units/Numbers **'1**' or **'Km'** in Formula

Comment: But how does this answer a question? In same way, I can say that I use double quotes on Friday only...